# ElasticSearch Adding Conditional Sub Search in ASP.Net C# using Nest 7.2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

How to convert the below SQL Query to Nest Code to search a Elastic Search index which contains mainly 2 columns 1. CATEGORY 2. COMPANY_NAME ?

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table 
WHERE 
COMPANY_NAME LIKE '%DATALIGENCE%' AND (CATEGORY LIKE 'A%' OR CATEGORY LIKE 'B%')
```

Below is my NEST code which is working fine without the Category condition :-

```
prefixText = {"prefixText":"DATALIGENCE","count":25}


                QueryContainer query = new MatchQuery
                {
                    //Field = Field<RawData>(p => p.company_name),
                    Analyzer = "standard",
                    Boost = 1.1,
                    Name = "named_query",
                    Field = "company_name",
                    //CutoffFrequency = 0.001,
                    Query = prefixText,
                    Fuzziness = Fuzziness.Auto,
                    //Fuzziness = Fuzziness.AutoLength(3, 6),
                    FuzzyTranspositions = true,
                    //MinimumShouldMatch = 1,
                    //FuzzyRewrite = MultiTermQueryRewrite.TopTermsBlendedFreqs(10),
                    Lenient = true,
                    //Operator = Operator.Or,
                    AutoGenerateSynonymsPhraseQuery = false
                    //MinimumShouldMatch = 50
                };

                var searchRequest = new SearchRequest("companylistindex")
                {
                    Query = query,
                    Size = 10,
                    MinScore = 1,
                    Sort = new List<ISort>
                        {
                        new FieldSort { Field = "_score", Order = Nest.SortOrder.Descending }
                        }
                    //Sort(sort => sort.OnField("_score").Descending())
                    //Sort = SortSpecialField.Score
                    //Sort = SortSpecialField.Score
                };
                var searchResults = client.Search<RawData>(searchRequest);
                //var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("{\"result\":true\"}");
                List<RawData> lstData = new List<RawData>();
                lstData = searchResults.Documents.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i use linq-fluent (if you dont have dataobject you will have to swap).
I assume your data are index correctly (no keyword...)

```
QueryContainer filterContainer = null;
            filterContainer &= Query<yourtype>.QueryString(q
                    => q.Query("DATALIGENCE").Fields(f => f.Field(fi => fi.company_name)));

            filterContainer &= Query<yourtype>.Bool(b => b.Should(
                        bs => bs.Prefix(p => p.CATEGORY , "A", rewrite: (MultiTermQueryRewrite)null),
                        bs => bs.Prefix(p => p.CATEGORY , "B", rewrite: (MultiTermQueryRewrite)null)
                        )
                );

Client.Search<yourtype>(s => s
            .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(m => filterContainer 
                )
            )
            ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I tried the above but it is giving me error... 
Error 21 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Nest.QueryContainer' because it is not a delegate type